# How to select non-matching rows from two mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, tableA and tableB as below:

**tableA:**

```
id | name       | age
---|------------|--------
1  | John       | 26
2  | Michal     | 30
3  | Watson     | 28
4  | samson     | 25
```

**tableB:**

```
name     | occupation
---------|---------------
John     | job
Michal   | business
watson   | job
```

I want to match two tables in such way that I can get non-matching row 'name:samson' from tableA. Which query (from PHP script) should I have to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this query in PHP. You will get the solution.

```
$qry = "SELECT a.* FROM tableA AS a, b.* FROM tableB AS b WHERE a.name <> b.name";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this you can use `NOT EXISTS` to find not matched rows

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM tableB
WHERE tableA.`name` = tableB.`name`)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `NOT IN` subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tableA
WHERE  name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM tableB)
```